# Expanded formatting is not working in visual studio 2010

Tags: css, visual-studio

My CSS files are displayed in collapsed style.  I want to change it to expanded style, but when I change it to expanded style and press okay, it still doesn't work!

Comment: Can you edit your question to share the relevant parts of your css?

Comment: you tried like this http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/compact-css-formatting-in-visual-studio.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the setting won't change your formatting. You have to reformat the document or select a block and reformat it.

Edit > Advanced > Format Document

If that doesn't work check if the setting is getting reset once you open and close Visual Studio - in this case you might want to try deleting your settings file and trying again (it's in ..\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings\ called CurrentSettings.vsssettings. Note that you will lose all your settings once you do this!

Actually it might be also worthwhile to check if you have update writes to that location before you try that and also try closing Visual Studio, starting it up as an administrator and trying it again.

And if all else fails, one last option is to find a machine where this works and copy the settings file over. Again note that you will lose all your settings once you do this!